# Angular component not loading under Outlook 2016 for Mac

Tags: angularjs, office-js

I am working on create a Outlook Add-in using Angular. For a sample i added task pane button to open up a side panel in outlook. After index page loading its open another component.

Problem is angular component not loading in Outlook 2016 mac, but it works Firefox, Chrome, Safari browsers.

How would you recommend carrying out such a problem?

Note : I have tested outlook on mac with Vorlon. Office.intialize not loading and got folllowing console messages.

1. Attempting to configure 'userAgent' with descriptor '{}' on object '[object Navigator]' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
2. Attempting to configure 'appVersion' with descriptor '{}' on object '[object Navigator]' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
3. Attempting to configure 'appName' with descriptor '{}' on object '[object Navigator]' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
4. Attempting to configure 'product' with descriptor '{}' on object '[object Navigator]' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
5. Attempting to configure 'vendor' with descriptor '{}' on object '[object Navigator]' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.

And also I published the addin and checked F12 to console messages in Outlook on windows. getting an error message "SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function."

This is my main.ts file

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

declare let Office:any;

Office.initialize = (reason: any) => {
  console.log('SampleAddin: initalizing office.js...');

  // bootstrap
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then((success: any) => {
      console.log('SampleAddin: bootstrap success', success);
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('SampleAddin: bootstrap error', error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFTnot getting any error it just loaded index page, not rendered the angular component in outlook Mac

Comment: Have you set up Vorlon so you can see the console messages? [Debugging with Vorlon.JS](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac#debugging-with-vorlonjs)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but i think dint test Vorlon with https. I will try. Do you have experience on Angular 2 add-in in mac? Is it works fine?

Comment: Many add-ins use Angular. Add-ins do require HTTPS, you cannot use them (even in dev) over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Without an error/warning, it is difficult to identify what might be going on. I'd recommend looking at the following resources:

1. [Tips for creating Office Add-ins with Angular](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2)
2. [Debug Office Add-ins on iPad and Mac](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac)
3. [OfficeDev/script-lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab) (OSS Word/Ppt/Excel Add-in using Angular)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have edited question with console log messages in outlook on mac. These log messages only shows in outlook mac.

Comment: I got  error saying  Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function. I have updated question with main.ts file.